# User (MS-Office) generated content - how?

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, content-management, user-generated-content

How can I allow users to share Microsoft Office generated content on an ASP.NET site?

For example usage, imagine a site similar to Stack Overflow.

George, writing a question, uses Word, Excel or OneNote to create content, and then inserts the content into the question area (probably copying it into the clipboard and then using some "paste from Office" widget).

Harry, who doesn't have MS-Office on his computer, can still see the content in his browser  that George has generated. If Harry wants to add content, he can use the built-in editor, same like in Stack Overflow, and have to be satisfied with lesser functionality.

Sue, who has MS-Office installed, can of course see the content in the browser just like Harry. In addition, she can "export" this content and process it in the application George used to generate it.

So, how do I do it? Would  Save/Export to HTML feature work? Any tools? Samples? Articles?

Office 2007 or later is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's solution to this is Sharepoint server.

Comment: First, thanks. I was not aware of this. However, the problem with MS servers, AFAIK, is that you can't use them for the general open Internet. Can I use Sharepoint server for thousands of internet users (say the number of SO users)? And if so, how much would it cost?